# CSS Display property prevents element hiding

Tags: css

HTML:

```
    <div id="addressinfo">
        <div>
            City and State<br>
            <input type = "text" id = "city" name = "city" placeholder="City" required><br>
            <div id="autocomplete" hidden></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#addressinfo div{
    display:inline-block;
    padding-right:50px;
    padding-top:10px;
    font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#autocomplete").prop("hidden",false);    //unhide the #autocomplete div
for(var i=0;i<=(count-1);i++){
    $("#"+i).click(function(){
        $("#city")[0].value = $(this).val();
        $("#autocomplete").prop("hidden",true);
    });
}
```

When I remove display:inline-block; from CSS, the #autocomplete div is successfully hidden when the jQuery click event occurs. But when the display propety exists, the div does NOT hide. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `hidden` with `display` - `display` will usually override `hidden`. From the HTML Living Standard:

> Because this attribute is typically implemented using CSS, it's also possible to override it using CSS. For instance, a rule that applies 'display: block' to all elements will cancel the effects of the hidden attribute. Authors therefore have to take care when writing their style sheets to make sure that the attribute is still styled as expected.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#the-hidden-attribute

You can simply use the jQuery `$("#autocomplete").hide()`. It will set `display` to `none` and your problem will be solved.